# J3.x: Is there a way to stop custom authentication plugins from automatically creating local users?

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, authentication

I have searched extensively, but have not found anything useful.  Can anyone offer any advice?

Thank you!

Comment: Automatically creating local users? Please elaborate

Comment: Did you tried looking into the custom plugin code and where it is adding users?

Comment: I have created a plugin (which does not have any code to add users) that authenticates with an external REST service using curl.  Immediately upon returning the JAuthenticationResponse object from the onUserAuthenticate event, a Joomla user is automatically created in the "Registered" group.  This is problematic because it presumably opens the authentication process up to issues like out-of-date passwords and account statuses, since I cannot disable the Joomla authentication plugin (which would lock me out of the back end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this issue.

Instead of worrying about syncing two authentication sources (external + regular Joomla), I did disable the Joomla authentication plugin, and updated my custom plugin to check if the code is being called from the front end or back end, and if back end, handle Joomla logins manually from the #__users table.

The users are still auto-created, but the problem of out-of-sync user accounts is now moot, and non-admin users in Joomla can be cleared automatically every night to prevent bloat.